# TypeScript React: Syntax Errors while trying to push a Component to an Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

import { Button } from 'antd';

import { IGridElementProps } from './Grid';

interface IProps extends IGridElementProps {
    label: string;
    color?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}

export default class RenderButton extends Component<IProps> {
    props: IProps;

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    clicked = () => {};

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    gridArea: this.props.gridAreaName
                }}
            >
                <Button
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: this.props.color,
                        borderColor: this.props.color
                    }}
                    onClick={this.clicked}
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                >
                    {this.props.label}
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Along with a helper class that contains an array of these components:

```
import FormButton from './FormButton';
import RenderButton from '../../components/Grid/RenderButton';

type GroupOptions = {
    colCount?: number;
    rowCount?: number;
    templareArea?: string;
    gridAreaName?: string;
    name: string;
};

export default class FormGroup {
    private renderButtons: Array<RenderButton>;

    constructor(options: GroupOptions) {
        this.renderButtons = [];
    }

    private updateTemplateArea = () => {
        let templateArea = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < this.rowCount; i++) {
            let row = "'";
            for (let j = 0; j < this.colCount; j++) {
                row += `${i}${j} `;
            }
            row = row.replace(/\s+(?=\S*$)/g, "'\n"); // REGEX used here
            templateArea += row;
        }
        this.templateArea = templateArea;
    };

    private addRenderButtons = (index: string) => {
        const detected = this.renderButtons.find(
            button => button.props.gridAreaName === index
        );
        if (!detected) {
            this.renderButtons.push(<RenderButton />); // ERROR thrown here
        }
    };
}
```

My goal is to later access the array of buttons through another component to display them in a list.

I have auto completion setup in my environment but when I try and fill in the props I don't get any suggestions. Likewise, when I run it, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in /path/app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
./app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts(90,51)
      TS1005: '>' expected.

ERROR in /home/.../classes/models/FormGroup.ts
./app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts(90,52)
      TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.

ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
./app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts(91,9)
      TS1005: ',' expected.

ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
./app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /home/.../app/classes/models/FormGroup.ts(90,37)
      TS2352: Conversion of type 'RegExp' to type 'RenderButton' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'RegExp' is missing the following properties from type 'RenderButton': props, clicked, render, context, and 4 more.
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file FormGroup file needed to have the .tsx extension instead of the .ts